# How to perform following search and replace in vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following string in the code at multiple places,

```
m_cells->a[ Id ]
```

and I want to replace it with

```
c(Id)
```

where the string `Id` could be anything including numbers also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A regular expression replace like below should do:

```
%s/m_cells->a\[\s\(\w\+\)\s\]/c(\1)/g
```

If you wish to apply the replacement operation on a number of files you could use the [`:bufdo`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers) command.

Answer (score 3):

Full explanation of @BasBossink's answer (as a separate answer because this won't fit in a comment), because regexes are awesome but non-trivial and definitely worth learning:
In Command mode (ie. type `:` from Normal mode), `s/search_term/replacement/` will replace the *first* occurrence of 'search_term' with 'replacement' on the *current line*.
The `%` before the `s` tells vim to perform the operation on *all* lines in the document. Any range specification is valid here, eg. `5,10` for lines 5-10.
The `g` after the last `/` performs the operation "globally" - all occurrences of 'search_term' on the line or lines, not just the first occurrence.
The "m_cells->a" part of the search term is a literal match. Then it gets interesting.
Many characters have special meaning in a regex, and if you want to use the character literally, without the special meaning, then you have to "escape" it, by putting a `\` in front.
Thus `\[` and `\]` match the literal '[' and ']' characters.
Then we have the opposite case: literal characters that we want to treat as special regex entities.
`\s` matches white*s*pace (space, tab, etc.).
`\w` matches "*w*ord" characters (letters, digits, and underscore `_`).
(`.` matches any character (except a newline). `\d` matches digits. There are more...)
If a character is not followed by a quantifier, then exactly *one* such character matches. Thus, `\s` will match one space or tab, but not fewer or more.
`\+` is a quantifier, and means "one or more". (`\?` matches 0 or 1; `*` (with *no* backslash) matches any number: zero or more. Warning: matching on zero occurrences takes a little getting used to; when you're first learning regexes, you don't always get the results you expected. It's also possible to match on an arbitrary exact number or range of occurrences, but I won't get into that here.)
`\(` and `\)` work together to form a "capturing group". This means that we don't just want to match on these characters, we also want to remember them specially so that we can do something with them later. You can have any number of capturing groups, and they can be nested too. You can refer to them later by number, starting at *1* (not 0). Just start counting (escaped) left-parantheses from the left to determine the number.
So here, we are matching a space followed by a group (which we will capture) of at least one "word" character followed by a space, within the square brackets.
Then section between the second and third `/` is the replacement text.
The "c" is literal.
`\1` means the first captured group, which in this case will be the "Id".
In summary, we are finding text that matches the given description, capturing part of it, and replacing the entire match with the replacement text that we have constructed.
Perhaps a final suggestion: `c` after the final `/` (doesn't matter whether it comes before or after the 'g') enables *c*onfirmation: vim will highlight the characters to be replaced and will show the replacement text and ask whether you want to go ahead. Great for learning.
Yes, regexes are complicated, but super powerful and well worth learning. Once you have them internalized, they're actually fairly easy. I suggest that, as with learning vim itself, you start with the basics, get fluent in them, and then incrementally add new features to your repertoire.
Good luck and have fun.

Comment: can you please answer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379121/vim-search-and-replace-a-variable-string