# vim search and replace a variable string

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have a paatern like this.

```
func(a, "a");
func(b, "b");
func(abc, "abc");
...
```

I wish to replace them with

```
func(a);
func(b);
func(abc);
...
```

In vim, how can i do it?

Comment: This is so basic (and variations of this have been asked here a quadrillion times) that you should have figured that out, e.g. by following one of the endless vi / Vim tutorials, or `:h :substitute`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I tried to figure it out and tried to change the regex expressions to comply with my need. But i am completely new to regex and was not able to do it succesfully. I still didnot understand the solution i accepted. I will take a look at them and understand. Apologies for asking a basic Q.

Comment: Next time, please post your attempts; this allows to address your misunderstandings. Here's a set of nice screencasts around Vim's regular expressions: http://vimcasts.org/categories/regular-expressions/

Comment: This is actually the first google result I came across when searching for the VIM regex replace syntax. That it had a negative score, was pretty baffling to me, hence I upvoted it to get it at least back to 0. Anyone care to explain how this is not a valid question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
:%s/func(\([^,]*\),\s*"\1"/func(\1/g
```

Comment: Hi, This is working well. But doesnt work if the func() is having three arguments.

Comment: @Manty Can you add some examples to your post?

Comment: When you post your question please post all use cases. Don't expect us to guess what kind of data you have. Complete question will result in complete answers.

Comment: @JS웃 I agree. My mistake. Aplogies.

Comment: @RSahu The problem is when string is having , not actually with 3 arguments. EX : fun(a, "abc,"); There are very few places like this in my code. So i can manually edit them. No issues. Thank you. I will accept the answer in a while.

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you were trying to figure out how to search and replace while leaving some substring in place, you do it with **capture groups**

[R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23379284/12393574) uses capture groups, but since I didn't know what they were called I couldn't look it up.

Here's another example of capture groups:

```
public User updateUser(String username, Optional<String> newUsername, Optional<String> newPassword, Optional<String[]> newRoles) {
// :s/\vOptional\<([a-zA-Z\[\]]*)\>/\1/g
public User updateUser(String username, String newUsername, String newPassword, String[] newRoles)
```

##### Search Definition

`:s` search only one line

##### Search String

`\v` assume any characters other than letters, numbers and underscores are special characters ("very magic" mode)

`Optional\<` match the literal phrase 'Optional<'

`([a-zA-Z\[\]]*)` capture a combination of letters and [ ]s to be used later

`\>` match the literal phrase '>'

##### Replace String

`\1` insert the first captured group

##### Global Flag

`g` replace every found instance, not just the first one

Answer (score 1):

This might work but can't say for sure until we can see more of the input:

```
%s/\v(.*), .*(\);)/\1\2/
```

Try this subsitution:

```
:%s/, ".\{-}"//
```

Explanation:

`%` - Run on whole file

`, "` - Matches the comma to first quote literally

`.\{-}"`  - Match zero or more characters, as few as possible till `"`

`//`  - Replace the matched pattern with nothing.

Comment: Working wel. Thank you. Please give me a while before i accept the answer. Also appreciate if you can explain in short. :)

Comment: Added some explanation, hope that helps.

Comment: This is not acceptable because, i have other lines in my huge source file where , " patterns are present. it replaces everywhere

Comment: @Manty - It would be better if you show more of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting a mass edit of the lines, it can be done using regex.  Follow these steps:

1. Place cursor at top line.
2. Shift-V to start a line visual selection.
3. Move cursor to bottom line to select all lines you want to modify.
4. Type ":" and you'll see ":'<,'>" appear at the bottom.
5. Type "s/, ".*");/);/" and hit enter.  The lines will change.

On #5, it's a regex search and replace. "s" denotes the operation, then the match pattern, then what to replace it with.  All delimited by a / key in between them and one at the end.

If you want more info, you can find some here:  http://vimregex.com/

Comment: I have other lines in my huge source file where , " patterns are present. it is replacing everywhere